# How to prevent a property in class not to store in session

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Suppose i have complex class

```
class Complex
{
    public ClassA A { get; set;}

    public ClassB B { get; set;}

    public string prop1 { get; set;}

    public string prop2 { get; set;}
}
```

Now i want to store this object in session. That i can do with following statement.

```
var complexObj = new Complex { 
// Initialize the proerties here.
}

Session["ComplexObj"] = complexObj;
```

Now, i don't want to store Class `A` object in a session (because we are not managing this value anywhere.). Can anyone tell me how we can do without changing the existing class.

Can we provide something like `data annotations` to that particular property?

Something like this

```
[NoSession]
public ClassA A { get; set;}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: There isn't something like that out of the box in MVC. However you could make a wrapper over the Session object to achieve the desired effect. It would create a new object of the same type, copy the underlying property values and set a default value for the properties that are marked with the attribute. You need to copy the initial object, because non-primitive values are passed by reference.

Comment: A simple method for copying an object is serializing and deserializing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use NonSerialized attribute but do not make auto property. Declare a private variable and make it NonSerialized and use it in public property.. old way..

> [NonSerialized]
>     private #dataType# _obj;
>
> public #dataType# Obj
>   {
>       get { return _obj; }
>       set { _obj= value; } 
>   }

Comment: Hey ravindra, any specific reason for not to use auto property? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

No way, would be better if you set `null` to the A property, for sample:

```
public Complex MyComplex
{
    get
    {
        return Session["ComplexObj"] as Complex
    }
    set
    {
        value.A = null; // set A to null
        Session["ComplexObj"] = value;
    }
}
```

On the other hand, you could serialize the object into a `Stream` and apply this object to session, but you should deserialize to read (in this case, you can apply the [`NonSerialized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx) attribute to ignore on the property on the serialization process, for sample:

In your `Complex` class, you could add the [`NonSerialized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx) attribute for the property you do not want to serialize:

```
class Complex
{
    [NonSerialized]
    public ClassA A { get; set;}

    public ClassB B { get; set;}

    public string prop1 { get; set;}

    public string prop2 { get; set;}
}
```

Implement some serialization helper methods to serializa into the Memorystream

```
public static MemoryStream SerializeToStream<T>(T o)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
    return stream;
}

public static T DeserializeFromStream<T>(MemoryStream stream)
{
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    T o = (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    return o;
}
```

And create a property to encapsulate the `Complex` object using the helper methods.

```
public Complex MyComplex
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["ComplexObj"] != null)
        {
            return DeserializeFromStream<MyComplex>((MemoryStream)Session["ComplexObj"]);
        }
        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["ComplexObj"] = SerializeToStream(value);
    }
}
```